# use of adverb: as tight as or tight as much as

Tags: comparative-constructions

We write:

> Then tie this part **as tight as** you want.

And we also write:

> Then tie this part **tight as much as** you want.

Is the first one more natural than the second one?

Comment: Your question doesn’t seem to match the title of your question. You may want to elaborate more or give your question a better title.

Comment: "Tie it tight as much as you want" isn't idiomatic or fluent.  The construction "as *adjective* as" is much more idiomatic.

Comment: I would use the first one. Less words is better and usually easier to comprehend, as long as the meaning is unchanged.